# Нужно получить начальное и конечное время текущего месяца

Tags: java, дата, datetime

Всем привет. Разбираюсь с вопросом времени в java. Нашел пару интересных задач, но одну мне кажется делаю не правильно. Надо получить начальное и конечное время текущего месяца (сек мин часы дни). Я сделал это как в примере ниже, но это немного по читерски. Как это сделать лучше ?

YearMonth month = YearMonth.now();

String first = month.atDay(1).toString(),

last = month.atEndOfMonth().toString();

```
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(last);
```

Comment: А почему _"по-читерски"_?  И что значит _"сделать лучше"_? Java Date/Time API и разрабатывалось для устранения велосипедов, которые нужно было изобретать при работе с `java.util.Date` и потоко-небезопасным `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: ну тут все ок, кроме указания часов, минут и секунд. Надо их добавить и все

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [TemporalAdjusters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html):

```
private static String getEndOfCurrentMonth() { //последний день месяца
return LocalDate.now()
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
    .toString();
  }
private static String getStartOfCurrentMonth() { //первый день месяца
return LocalDate.now()
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
    .toString();
  }
```

---

PS но и ваш вариант тоже работает.

Answer (score 0):

Если задача состоит в получении именно *времени*, а не только даты первого и последнего дня текущего месяца, то следует применить ещё пару читерских методов для конвертации `LocalDate` в `LocalDateTime`:

- [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--) (также есть вариант с выбором часового пояса [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay(ZoneId zoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-)):

```java
LocalDateTime f = month.atDay(1).atStartOfDay();
System.out.println(f); // 2021-10-01T00:00
```

- набор методов [`LocalDateTime::atTime(int h, int m, int s, int nano)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atTime-int-int-), позволяющих задать время в виде часов, минут, секунд, наносекунд
- метод [`LocalDateTime::atTime(LocalTime locTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atTime-java.time.LocalTime-), позволяющий выбрать текущее время, используя `LocalTime::now`:

```java
LocalDateTime e = month.atEndOfMonth().atTime(LocalTime.now());
System.out.println(e); // 2021-10-31T19:42:05.477406700
```

---

Также можно сконвертировать дату в `OffsetDateTime` при помощи метода [LocalDate::atTime(OffsetTime off)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atTime-java.time.OffsetTime-)